# Accordion header content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created accordion in javascript. I would like to make accordion header content size smaller (50% percent). However I could not able to figure that out.

```
$.each(myData.offsetFormations, function(i,aut) {
            headerList = '<h3><ul><li contenteditable="true">'+
                '<text class="formationName">'+ aut.FormationName + '</text>'+
                ' | ' +
                '<text class="bitSize">'+this.BitSize.toFixed(2) + '</text>'+
                ' | ' +
                '<text class="bitType">'+this.BitType + '</text>'+
                '</li></ul></h3>';

            wellNameList = '<div class="table-holder"><table>';

            $.each(myData.wellList, function(k,mano){
                if(aut.AssociatedwellList.some(function(w) { return w.WellName === mano.WellName; }))
                    {
                    wellNameList += '<td><div>'+ mano.WellName+'</div></td>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                 wellNameList += '<td style="color:gray;" ><div>'+ mano.WellName+'</div></td>';
                    }
                });

            wellNameList += '</table></div>';

            headerList += '<div>'+wellNameList +'</div>';
            $(headerList).appendTo('#accordion'); 
        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `ul` elements have a 1em top and bottom margin, which is causing your boxes to have an additional 2em of height.

You can remove this with:

```
.ui-accordion ul {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xg7cr0g4/44/